# Whitespaces being added when echo

Tags: batch-file

When I want to echo a command with variables in it, whitespaces are being added between and my command doesn't work :/

Code :

```
@echo on
chcp 65001 > nul
if exist Sauvegarde.bat del Sauvegarde.bat
set /p path=Donner le chemin du dossier à sauvegarder (dossier compris):
set /p hote=Donner l'hôte(ou ip) du serveur FTP :
set /p utilisateur=Donner l'utilisateur : 
set /p mdp=Donner le mot de passe : 
echo @echo on > Sauvegarde.bat  
set path=%path% >> Sauvegarde.bat  
set hote=%hote% >> Sauvegarde.bat  
set utilisateur=%utilisateur% >> Sauvegarde.bat  
set mdp=%mdp% >> Sauvegarde.bat  
echo :menu >> Sauvegarde.bat  
echo echo "/------------------------------\" >> Sauvegarde.bat
echo echo "|         1-Sauvegarde         |" >> Sauvegarde.bat
echo echo "|  2-Activer Sauvegarde Auto   |" >> Sauvegarde.bat
echo echo "|   3-Recommencer la config    |" >> Sauvegarde.bat
echo echo "|           4-Fermer           |" >> Sauvegarde.bat
echo echo "\------------------------------/" >> Sauvegarde.bat
echo set /p choix=Entrer un choix :  >> Sauvegarde.bat
echo if %%choix%% == 1 GOTO sauvegarder >> Sauvegarde.bat
echo if %%choix%% == 2 GOTO autosauvegarde >> Sauvegarde.bat
echo if %%choix%% == 3 GOTO recommencer >> Sauvegarde.bat
echo if %%choix%% == 4 GOTO quitter >> Sauvegarde.bat
echo echo Entrer un chiffre entre 1 et 4 !!! >> Sauvegarde.bat
echo goto menu >> Sauvegarde.bat
echo :sauvegarder >> Sauvegarde.bat
echo set filename=Sauvegarde_%%date:~-4,4%%-%%date:~-7,2%%-%%date:~10,2%%.zip >> Sauvegarde.bat
echo .\lib\zip.exe -r -u %%filename%% test >> Sauvegarde.bat
echo .\lib\winscp.com /command "open ftp://%utilisateur%:%mdp%@%hote%" "put %filename%" /log="script.log">> Sauvegarde.bat
pause
start Sauvegarde.bat
pause
```

This line is concerned :

```
echo .\lib\winscp.com /command "open ftp://%utilisateur:%mdp@%hote" "put %filename%" /log="script.log">> Sauvegarde.bat
```

And the output comes with spaces between :
The X is to hide my login

```
.\lib\winscp.com /command "open ftp://XXXXXXXX   :XXXXXXXXX   @XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX   " "put " /log="script.log"
```

Comment: We have no idea what you have `set` as `%utilisateur%`, `%mdp%`, `%hote%` or `%filename%`, but the latter has no value suggesting that it at least has no value at the time it is used. You need to provide the rest of the code, or at least the portion(s) which cover the `set`ting of each of those variables. Also we need to know whether or not you have invoked delayed expansion and whether any of those variables are being set within a code block. Those should be apended to your question using the [edit facility](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48429918/edit), not placed in a comment!

Comment: Yeah sorry i just forgot to put the whole code

Comment: Never overwrite the system PATH variable unless you are sure what you are doing.

Comment: Yeah I change it

Comment: Could I ask why? ...why echo an entire script to another script then start it? Also if you take a look at `Sauvegarde.bat` you'll clearly see what's happening during the pointless echoing.

Answer (score 2):

`filename` isn't being set, probably

```
echo set filename=...
```

should be without the `echo` and redirection and should be moved to before the `echo @echo on > Sauvegarde.bat` line.

You have many lines like

```
set utilisateur=%utilisateur% >> Sauvegarde.bat
```

It seems illogical to do this - perhaps you meant `ECHO set...` Also, you have a variable number of spaces at the end of the lines - this may be the source of the accumulated stray spaces. It appears your run-report is created by the batch that *this* batch creates.

This is also why the syntax

```
set "var=value"
```

is used - the value will be assigned to `var`, regardless of trailing spaces on the line.

Are you aware that

```
(
 echo this
 echo that
 echo something else
)>filename
```

will create a new file `filename` containing the accumulated `echo`es?

Answer (score 0):

An example to show you the `echo`ing, the use of `choice` and to fix a few other things:

```bat
@Echo Off
Rem ChCp 65001 > Nul
Set /P "pth=Donner le chemin du dossier … sauvegarder (dossier compris): "
Set /P "hote=Donner l'h“te(ou ip) du serveur FTP: "
Set /P "utilisateur=Donner l'utilisateur: "
Set /P "mdp=Donner le mot de passe: "

(   Echo @Echo Off
    Echo :menu
    Echo Echo "/------------------------------\"
    Echo Echo "|         1-Sauvegarde         |"
    Echo Echo "|  2-Activer Sauvegarde Auto   |"
    Echo Echo "|   3-Recommencer la config    |"
    Echo Echo "|           4-Fermer           |"
    Echo Echo "\------------------------------/"
    Echo Choice /C 1234 /M "Entrer un choix"
    Echo If ErrorLevel 4 GoTo quitter
    Echo If ErrorLevel 3 GoTo recommencer
    Echo If ErrorLevel 2 GoTo autosauvegarde
    Echo :sauvegarder
    Echo Set "filename=Sauvegarde_%%date:~-4,4%%-%%date:~-7,2%%-%%date:~-10,2%%.zip"
    Echo .\lib\zip.exe -r -u %%filename%% test
    Echo .\lib\winscp.com /command "open ftp://%%utilisateur%%:%%mdp%%@%%hote%%" "put %%filename%%" /log="script.log"
) > "Sauvegarde.bat"
Pause
Call "Sauvegarde.bat"
Pause
```

I've `Rem`arked the second line, for which I saw no need, *you may however decide otherwise*, and removed those lines which were no longer required.

*Remember that you need to complete the other labels for your menu items*

**Note**

On lines `3` and `4` you will notice that there are characters which appear different from those in your questions script. They were as a result of pasting the characters directly from my `cmd.exe` output. If those characters do not render properly in your tests then please feel free to replace `…` with `à` and `“` with `ô` as necessary.